# asp.net Membership.CreateUser() not creating user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My tables have been created in my database for both aspnet_Membership, aspnet_Users for Membership and I AspNetUsers since I was using a different way before. Anyways, my connection is good to my database since it was inserting users into AspNetUsers but I want to use Membership so when I call Membership.CreateUser(), it doesn't insert into my table aspnet_Membership.

Any ideas?

Web.config

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" 
          connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=Application; Integrated Security=True;"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <membership defaultProvider="MembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="10">
      <providers>
        <add name="MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=Application; Integrated Security=True;" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="Application"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Register.aspx.cs

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Username.Text.Equals("") && !Password.Text.Equals("") && !Email.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(Username.Text, Password.Text, Email.Text, "", "", true, out createStatus); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value for `createStatus` after your call to CreateUser?

Comment: The enum value can't be null. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipcreatestatus(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't understand, it still should insert my user into the database, right?

Comment: what happens when you pass null instead of empty strings for the 4th & 5th param:

Membership.CreateUser(Username.Text, Password.Text, Email.Text, null, null, true, out createStatus);

Comment: null doesn't work and gives me quest errors but if i keep string null, it redirects to home page so it seems to successfully create user, just not add to db

Comment: Is that correct?  The definition of the membership provider is specifying both a connection string, and the **name** of a connection string.  Wouldn't you want one or the other?  Also try adding a `<clear />` tag first in the list of providers, to ensure that you're not picking up some other default provider.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of your `createStatus` enum to see why it failed to create the user. You can also use the [Website Administration Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssa0wsyf.aspx) to create the user manually and see if you get any more informative error messages.

Comment: createStatus comes back as "success"